# 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Can't use nil for keys or values on PFObject. Use NSNull for values.' (previous answers do not fix it)

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, pfobject

I have my app where users post something and other users can comment it,
then, I use the "SendYourOpinion" method to store that

```
 - (IBAction)SendYourOpinion:(id)sender {

        PFObject *opinion = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Opinions"];
        opinion[@"content"] = self.txtFieldOpinion.text;
        opinion[@"userId"] = [PFUser currentUser];
        [opinion saveInBackground];

    }
```

And the error in the title appears, then I read previous answers and I didn't fixed my problem

Comment: Is `self.txtFieldOpinion.text` nil?

Comment: Print out the values of `self.txtFieldOpinion.text` and `[PFUser currentUser]`.  Is either of them `nil`?

Answer (score 1):

`self.txtFieldOpinion.text` or `[PFUser currentUser]` is `nil`.

You need to check for `nil` and assign an object instead. You cannot assign `nil` as a value (as is stated in the error message that you received).

```
    PFObject *opinion = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Opinions"];
    opinion[@"content"] = self.txtFieldOpinion.text ? self.txtFieldOpinion.text : [NSNull null];
    opinion[@"userId"] = [PFUser currentUser] ? [PFUser currentUser] : [NSNull null];
    [opinion saveInBackground];
```

Comment: [PFUser currentUser] is nil, I see that in the Dashboard (undefined), but what am I missing ? That's a pointer to the "_User" class. What is the problem at that stage ?

Comment: I have no idea. You have only posted a small segment of your source code. The answer to the question that you originally asked is now found. If you have further questions, you should post them in a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Indicates no value assigned (nil), quite possible when you attempt to assign hardcoded values, or type that Parse can't resolve. E.g if you have an attribute of an object whose type is `BOOLEAN` and you do

`object[@"status"] = FALSE`, or 0 (you will get the error message)

Correct:

```
NSNumber* status = [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]; //passing FALSE as status
object[@"status"] = status;
```

Parse would resolve it as a value assigned via a type and resolve it